# Memory leaks when using a C# COM interop class from C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I am trying to use a COM object written in C# from C++ and I don't understand why the memory becomes greater and greater.

In C#, we have a very simple COM interface :

```
public enum COMObjectErrorCodes
{
    OK,
    Error,
}

public interface IInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This interface has only one method which does nothing
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    COMObjectErrorCodes Func();
}

public class InterfaceImpl : IInterface
{
    public COMObjectErrorCodes Func()
    { return COMObjectErrorCodes.OK; }
}

public interface ICOMObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This simple methods permits to get another interface
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oInt">The returned interface</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    COMObjectErrorCodes GetInterface(out IInterface oInt);
}

public class COMObjectImpl : ICOMObject
{       
    public COMObjectErrorCodes GetInterface(out IInterface oInt)
    {
        oInt = new InterfaceImpl();
        return COMObjectErrorCodes.OK;
    }
}
```

And the C++ client which is using this COM interop class:

```
// 0. Initialize COM
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

if (hr == S_OK || hr == S_FALSE || hr == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
{
    // 1. Creates an instance of the COM object
    ICOMObjectPtr pFactory(__uuidof(COMObjectImpl));

    // 2. Use it in a loop
    COMObjectErrorCodes err;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        // 1. Get the interface
        IInterface* pI = NULL;
        gPtr->GetInterface(&pI, &err);
        // 2. Do the call
        pI->Func(&err);
        // 3. Release the interface (don't worry, it returns 0, I verified !)
        pI->Release();
    }

    // 4. Release the COM object
    pFactory->Release();
}

// 5. Uninitialize COM
CoUninitialize();
```

And my problem is if you display the memory before step 0, and after step 5, it has increased by more than 100 Mo (100 bytes per call since I made 1,000,000 calls).

Does somebody know what could be causing this?

Comment: maybe you could free allocation of `pI` (just guessing)

Comment: You can not infer to a memory leak. It can be that the memory is just not returned to the OS. You need a memory profiler (that also covers unmanaged memory) to see if your memory is cleaned up.

Comment: not sure if there is a Marshal.ReleaseComObject equivalent for c++. but if I does then you need to call it

Comment: Thanks for all your comments : some precisions : for Jean-François : pI->Release() must do the job (in COM, Release') decrease a counter and when it is the last reference, it frees the memory

Comment: for Sefe : I used the VS 2015 Performance profiler, and it saws some memory leaks, in the native heap

Comment: and for Steve : the equivalent is the Release() which I called ;-(... But on the server side (C#) I asked myself if I did not have to call some Marshal.ReleaseXXX on the returned objects ?

Comment: Your CoIniitialize() call is wrong.  Always use CoInitializeEx(), forces you to think about the argument.  Matters a lot here, you must select MTA since you did not implement the requirements of an STA thread.  Consequence is that the CLR's finalizer thread will deadlock.  Yeah, you'll notice that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Hans Passant : I now use CoInitializeEx... But I have still the same memory leaks ! Do you think it is due to the CLR Finalizer which are in deadlock ? And how can I prevent this ? Finalizers are called on C# side, so I must modify something in C# ?

Comment: To be more precise on the memory leak size, I did the test again (with exactly the code in the example and I obtained : for 1 000 000 loops : 25 Mo (25 bytes lost per loop), and for 1 000 loops... 553 ko (500 bytes lost per loop) ! Sorry but I don't understand these results !!